# SecureString in file "randomly" stops working

Tags: powershell, credentials, securestring

I developed a PowerShell script which processes certain files and transfers them via SFTP.
To do so, it uses the SecureString type to read and decrypt the SFTP user credentials from an encrypted text file whenever the credentials are needed to authenticate to the SFTP server. This is required because I am not allowed to store the credentials as plain text in a file (or in the script itself) because it would otherwise not pass the next security audit.

In addition to the script there is a separate configuration script which must be run once to specify the sftp user credentials, encrypt them and save them to the text file. This is the (simplified) code of that configuration script:

```
Write-Output "Please enter the username of the SFTP user."
$username = Read-Host
Write-Output "Please enter the password of the SFTP user"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$username | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "$scriptroot\Credentials.dat"
$password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Append "$scriptroot\Credentials.dat"
```

Basically the two scripts work just fine and do what they are supposed to. However, for whatever reason the decryption will stop working once I log out and then log back into windows again.

I do not understand why this stops working over and over again and I am not sure what to do about it. Does anybody know a way to figure out why the decryption stops working due to me logging out of the system? The script does not even run under my own user, it is executed as a scheduled task which runs under a completely different AD user.

I also read that Microsoft no longer recommends using SecureString for new projects, but then what is the alternative that can be used instead? How else am I supposed to securely store user credentials in a file without having some sort of plain text decryption key stored in the script or in another file somewhere?

Comment: I suspect that your issue is related to **Fast Logon Optimization and Fast Startup on Group Policy**, see: [Understand the Effect of Fast Logon Optimization and Fast Startup on Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj573586(v%3Dws.11)). Basically: The user is logged on, you scheduled task is initiated but the rest of the network might take minutes before it is actually initiated under the concerned user account. I recommend to check whether the script can ping the domain first.

Comment: @iRon But would that permanently stop the script from working? The script is not even meant to run only when a user is logged on. I just found out by accident that it stops working when I log off and then log back in again. The strangest thing to me is that the script stops working when I log off and on again while my user is not even used to execute the scheduled task.

Comment: I think you need to separate a **Scheduled Task** issue from an **PowerShell** issue. To check for a **Scheduled Task** issue; enable the `history` tab. Are there any errors? To check a PowerShell (excluding the Task Scheduler) issue: `runas /user:<user> cmd` under the credentials of the specific user, start the script. Does it run? Any errors?

Comment: @iRon The scheduled task itself is not the problem and there are no errors of any kind logged in the history tab either. I can reproduce the issue perfectly by simply executing the script manually under the same user which would normally run the scheduled task. I would neither call this a Scheduled Task issue nor a PowerShell issue, it's a DPAPI issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's really kind of odd the to decrypt just stops working, that sounds environmental. However, why are you doing this, this way...

```
Write-Output "Please enter the username of the SFTP user."
$username = Read-Host
Write-Output "Please enter the password of the SFTP user"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$username | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "$scriptroot\Credentials.dat"
$password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Append "$scriptroot\Credentials.dat"
```

... vs going one fo these routes.

```
$UserCreds = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter the username of the SFTP credentials'
$UserCreds.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
$UserCreds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
<#
# Results

postanote
password
#>
```

Or this way,

```
Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter the username of the SFTP credentials.' | 
Export-Clixml -Path 'D:\temp\SFTPUserCreds.xml'
Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\SFTPUserCreds.xml'
<#
# Results

<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">postanote</S>
      <SS N="Password">01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000bd0a9dd27ffa41419fb2b289838ebe6400000000020000000000106600000001000020000000ad2e4c96413a3e93e461f600e98f72aa5
e3493bde41ac40491bfd4bedc462152000000000e8000000002000020000000e0016657a9f6e545b55876fa8095143c08046f1361baec0f693a1e823cc6ee0d200000006949857c09b23099dab66fdc3a7e4f7637970dbd3aa13
be11fda7c8de63df70e40000000f9a266cbb34440f64d9a2bdeaaec3a6cda483138e0be29323ca0a523ac475e169793557e74dd208e3d4292aa4fbe5b90fc7023d41c4dd6d01f819366e0587885</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
#>
```

no decrypt needed, just pass the variable names

```
($UserCreds = Import-Clixml -Path 'D:\Temp\SFTPUserCreds.xml')
<#
# Results

UserName                      Password
--------                      --------
postanote System.Security.SecureString
#>
```

Or this way

```
Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter the username of the SFTP credentials.' | 
Export-PSCredential -RegistryPath 'HKCU:\software\SFTP' -Name SFTPUserCreds
$UserCred = Import-PSCredential -RegistryPath 'HKCU:\Software\SFTP' -Name SFTPUserCreds

# Or just use Windows Credential Manager
Find-Module -Name '*CredentialManager*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                          Repository Description                                                                        
------- ----                          ---------- -----------                                                                        
2.0     CredentialManager             PSGallery  Provides access to credentials in the Windows Credential Manager                   
...
```

So, even based on what you've read about SecureString, it's still a thing for most folks, though based on what I show above, I am not sure why.

Anyway, give one or more of the above a shot to see if that allows you more consistancy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main thing I want to find out is why it randomly stops working. I agree that your suggestions appear to be better solutions for getting the credentials, but wouldn't they have no effect regarding the actual issue that I am facing? Unfortunately I cannot simply test your suggestions because the problem occurs too randomly and I cannot reproduce it without knowing the actual reason that causes it. I need to provide a solution until the end of this week, and without knowing the root cause of the issue I cannot fix it. Is there maybe an alternative?

Comment: Again, stop working and error out are not the same thing. You have to trace this and determine under what conditions it stops. Working code, with no physical changes to stop working does not indicate a code problem. Hence, my saying this has to be environmental. Random items have a reason, and since it not a specific code failure, that means interference from something else. You have to put a watch on this process using this code, and trap for operational failure and look for correlation. You are calling from a static file, so, unless someone changed it or has it locked, it should be readable.

Comment: After some more testing I figured out that the decryption actually stops working as soon as the user logs out and then logs back in again. How is this possible and is there any way how I can avoid that issue? I found a very similar issue by someone else on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7me35c/securestring_in_file_not_working_after_reboot/) but there are no helpful answers for it yet.

Comment: Do they get a new profile on login?  Or is it a different user?

Comment: I would look into dpapi since Powershell uses this to encrypt/decrypt credentials with the securestring cmdlets. Mandatory and roaming profiles can also cause these kind of issues.

Comment: Yet, based on the OP's code block shown, the OP is creating a fresh file each time the code is used. So, the user is always providing current creds, unless the OP says different. So, even if this was a new user profile/roaming profile, etc., the interactive user is always entering their creds.

Comment: @postanote The "fresh file" is only created ONCE during the installation of the script. After doing so, the code which creates the file is not executed again.

Comment: @js2010 What do you mean by "new profile on login"? The thing I don't understand is that it is not even the user who is actually used to execute the script which logs off and then logs back in again, it is the user who configured the scheduled task which then runs the script.

Comment: @bluuf2 What are "mandatory and roaming profiles" and how can I check if the user which is configured to run the script falls under that category?

Comment: @bluuf I just got the information that neither mandatory nor roaming profiles are used to run the script. However it does work fine with a local user. What else could be the problem?